# Permission denied when trying to move folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, sublimetext3

Im my folder structure I have the file app/views/topics and app/views/posts. I would like to make the following directory change:

app/views/posts/_form.html.erb -> app/views/topics/posts/_form.html.erb

But when tried i get the error

-bash: app/views/posts/_form.html.erb: Permission denied

What goes wrong here? I can do it manually....

---

Comment: can you show us command what you use for change directory?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo mv source_location destination_location

sudo mv app/views/posts/_form.html.erb  app/views/topics/posts/_form.html.erb
```

with admin rights try to move with above commands. Provide admin password if needed.

Otherwise, add write permission to your views folder(being at root location of your project)

```
chmod 777 -R  app/views/
```

Comment: Why using sudo ? It's maybe only a chmod problem, so better fix that instead of forcing this !

Comment: then on top of your root folder you can add  permission 
 chmod 777 -R  app/views/

Comment: even worse! Why would you like to make every file world readable / writable / executable ??
Better check if the destination folder exist, first !

Comment: btw, OP says "What goes wrong here? I can do it manually....", so better check what does he use first ;)